# Paypal API: The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts -> 10413

Tags: php, express-checkout, paypal

My logic is that `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0` is the quantity of the product, then `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0` is the value of the singular product. But i keep getting this error.

```
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => Pacote de 150 crÃ©ditos
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0] => EF8D9B3E83
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 4
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 10.00
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0] => 2.30
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 40.00
[PAYMENTINFO_0_TAXAMT] => 9.20
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 49.20
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => USD
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
[RETURNURL] => http://localhost/www/kompite/compraCreditos.php
[CANCELURL] => http://localhost/www/kompite/pagamentoCancelado.php
[METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
[VERSION] => 84
[NOSHIPPING] => 1
```

I can't find where i am goin wrong. The error code that i get is 10413